# How to get bot to say role but not ping?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I get my bot to say the name of a role without pinging the role itself? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Role.name`.
It will return a string, rather than a Role object, which you could send as regular text.

Here's the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=name), it's your best friend.

Comment: I did do that but it still sent the ping. Idk if i did something wrong or not

Comment: Do you mean it sent @Role instead of just Role?

Comment: Guess I just failed to do it correctly or some kind of glitch... I reset the code and then it worked.